# Stop a method and wait for user input

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpf-4.0

My program's written in C# and has a GUI in WPF. When one button is clicked, the method `StopAndGo()` is invoked.

The problem is that I want this method to stop at certain points, wait for user input, and then continue.

I guess this could be done with multithreading, but since I've never studied that topic, I want to be sure that it could be done, and whether it would be hard to accomplish, before studying it.

Can you give me some guidelines on what needs to be done?

Thanks.

Comment: When StopAndGo() is waiting for user input is it displaying a prompt of some sort?

Comment: StopAndGo() is waiting for a button in the GUI to be clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Well first and foremost, I don't think multi-threading is the way to go here.  If you want the method to stop at certain points you should code it as such to display popup boxes, text boxes, or any other area to receive the input.  So you will need multiple methods to handle this and inside the main method you can call other methods to create these waiting points.

Comment: Right, no need to get into threads if you can display a dialog of some sort (an inputbox, a custom dialog prompting for the data you need, etc). If it is a dialog then you can create the form, call ShowDialog on the form and handle the result of ShowDialog (DialogResult.OK, Cancel, Yes, No, etc depending on your form)

Comment: It's called a 'wizard'.  Many of them in Visual Studio.  Project + Add New Item + Report Wizard for example.

Comment: @Hans this seemed like quite the homework question and as such I provided guidance.

Comment: The problem is that StopAndGo() is in a class that should be independent from the GUI class. The GUI is the one that creates the class which contains the StopAndGo() method. So StopAndGo() is not able to create any window.

Comment: Unless I am missing something you can change `StopAndGo` to do whatever it is you want.  However, what I said is to utilize multiple methods.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to do this is to use nested message pumps via DispatcherFrame
http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/WPF-Modal-Controls-Via-DispatcherFrame-%28Nested-Message-Pumps%29.aspx

Updated link:
http://deanchalk.com/wpf-modal-controls-via-dispatcherframe-nested-message-pumps/

Comment: Updated link: http://dean.codes/wpf-modal-controls-via-dispatcherframe-nested-message-pumps/

Answer (score 0):

Use ManualResetEvent class. Start a thread that executes StopAndGo(); Inside of the context of that thread call

```
 this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Infinite,false);
```

when your user is done with the input, call

```
this.manualResetEvent.Set();
```

that will let the other thread know to proceed with stopANdgo

Comment: You don't want WaitOne(0, false). If you do WaitOne with a timeout of zero it will return immediately and tell you whether the handle was set, it will not block.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to go with Multi-threading when your method has a background nature, and you do not want to lock the UI while that method executes.

For waiting scenarios you probably need to go with synchronization objects, like `ManualResetEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

If your code can't proceed without user input, modal dialogs are a good way to avoid multiple threads.

```
DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();

// Show window modally 
// NOTE: Returns only when window is closed
Nullable<bool> dialogResult = dialogBox.ShowDialog();
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx